# dynamically select the connection string to the actively available database in entity framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, model-view-controller, connection-string

Currently, we are using two servers with the same database name and settings in it. I would like to take the connection string for the one which is active or the one which I can easily connect to. Say for instance sometimes we have a power cut in the place where the server-1 is located so I can use the server-2 as it is located in a different place.

Here I am using a connection string helper class in .NET for one without entity framework but I am not able to achieve it for entity framework.

in web.config

```
<add name="dbAdo1a" connectionString="connection for Server-1" providerName="abc" />
<add name="dbAdo1b" connectionString="connection for Server-2" providerName="abc" />
```

in C#

```
public class ConnectionStringHelper
    {
        private static readonly Timer Timer;
        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> BestConnectionStrings;
        private const int LoopCount = 3;
        static ConnectionStringHelper()
        {
            BestConnectionStrings = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();
            for (var i = 1; i <= LoopCount; i++)
            {
                GetQuickOneSync(i);
            }
            Timer = new Timer(Constants.ConnectionRefreshTimeout * 1000);
            Timer.Elapsed += async (sender, e) => await HandleTimerElapsed(sender, e).ConfigureAwait(false);
            Timer.AutoReset = false;
            Timer.Start();
        }


        public static string GetConnectionString(int wareHouseId)
        {
            if (!BestConnectionStrings.ContainsKey(wareHouseId))
            {
                return string.Empty;    // just swallow the error if no connection available
            }

            return BestConnectionStrings[wareHouseId];
        }

        private static async Task HandleTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Find the quickies for each of the connection strings
                var sw = new Stopwatch();
                sw.Start();
                // TODO - three sets of ConnectionStrings for now, make dynamic
                for (var i = 1; i <= LoopCount; i++)
                {
                    await GetQuickOne(i).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                Timer.Start();
            }

            async Task GetQuickOne(int wareHouseId)
            {
                var quickone = string.Empty;
                var quickest = long.MaxValue;
                var sw = new Stopwatch();
                for (var c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
                {
                    var cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[$"dbAdo{wareHouseId}{c}"]?.ConnectionString;
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cs)) break;
                    sw.Restart();
                    // open connection and see how long it takes
                    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(cs))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            await connection.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                        }
                        catch (Exception exception)
                        {
                            continue;   // move on
                        }

                        var milliseconds = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                        if (milliseconds < quickest) // quickest so far?
                        {
                            quickest = milliseconds;
                            quickone = cs;
                        }

                        if (milliseconds <= Constants.ConnectionOkThreshold) // is ok if quickest under the threshold, go no further
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                BestConnectionStrings[wareHouseId] = quickone;
            }
        }

        private static void GetQuickOneSync(int wareHouseId)
        {
            var quickone = string.Empty;
            var quickest = long.MaxValue;
            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            for (var c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
            {
                var cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[$"dbAdo{wareHouseId}{c}"]?.ConnectionString;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cs)) break;
                sw.Restart();
                // open connection and see how long it takes
                using (var connection = new SqlConnection(cs))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {
                        continue;   // move on
                    }

                    var milliseconds = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                    if (milliseconds < quickest) // quickest so far?
                    {
                        quickest = milliseconds;
                        quickone = cs;
                    }

                    if (milliseconds <= Constants.ConnectionOkThreshold) // is ok if quickest under the threshold, go no further
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(quickone))
                BestConnectionStrings[wareHouseId] = quickone;
        }
    }
```

I would like to do the same kind of set up for entity framework using System.Data.Entity.DbContext class. Where I should be able to pass the name of the connection string from web config and check it is actively available and it should redirect to it.

Comment: How have you tried and what does not work with entity framework db context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your need, i can propose a solution. I am assuming you already have supplied a default connection string for EF.

Now you can do like this.

**Step-1.** Create an extension method for EF DB Context:

public static class ConnectionTools
{

```
public static void CheckConnection(this DbContext source)
{

    if (!source.Database.Exists())
    {
        //TODO: logic to read all your connection string into a list
        string connectionStrings = new List<string>();
        foreach (var connection in connectionStrings)
        {
            //set new connection and check
            source.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connection;
            if (source.Database.Exists())
            {
            //break loop
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Step-2.** At calling part do something like this:

-

```
public void SomeOperation()
{
    //assuming you already have your context injected
    var employees = _context.CheckConnection().Employees.ToList();
}
```

Comment: A guess it is better to add some sort of a cache for available connections, because if first connection in the list is unavailable, it can take long time before it will timeout, so all the operation will be delayed.

Comment: Yeah i agree, could be done. I just wanted to show him the idea how you can do it using EF.